# What date is 74029 on an IBM Mainframe?

Tags: ibm, mainframe

I have an old printout of a Fortran code.

It's a simple code intended for educational purposes.

The header is:

FORTRAN IV G LEVEL 21, MAIN, DATE=74029, 15/28/03, PAGE 001

I assume it's from an IBM mainframe in Israel, if it helps. I don't know what system.

Does anyone know when was it printed?

Comment: How old is the printout?  Wouldn't the date be March 28, 2015 (15/28/03)?

Comment: Should be much older than that. I got a suggestion that the date is the 29th day of 1974 which makes sense but I am not sure.

Comment: I was using FORTRAN IV in 1976-9, so 1974 makes sense.

Comment: @HananCohen Perhaps it is the 29th ***week*** of the year. Not the 29th day. This was a standard already well-established for ICs by 1974. But the '0' does give me some question. So perhaps you may also be right.

Comment: The date format used at that time was YYDDD.

Comment: (Potentially) Interesting aside: the YYDDD format is still used in [BACS files](https://faq.webpayrolltraining.co.uk/5111.htm) as part of the UK's electronic payment systems.

Comment: And we still have a way to format that in many standard libraries, for example, [C](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) and [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) - as %y%j.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### TL;DR: `DATE=74029` reads as: Year (19)74, Day 029 (Jan 29th),

It's an [Ordinal Date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date) in truncated form, expressed in terms of 2 digit year and 3 digit day of the year.

> Does anyone know when was it printed?

No. That would have been noted on the spool header page. Date/time on each listing page, which this seems to be, is the date/time the compilation was done. Printing could have happened at any later moment in time - and usually was - depending on numbers of printers available, spool queue and, most important, when the computing center had decided to let them run at all (*1)

---

### Details

It was and still is the base format in many mainframe applications as it avoids all pitfalls of [date notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country). Kind of an early form of internationalization. In addition it's quite helpful for date calculation, especially in scripting (JCL), as it takes out the irregularity of month length (*2).

In daily EDP life this was confusingly called a Julian Date. Confusingly, as in Astronomy a [Julian Date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Julian_date_calculation) is a [Julian Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) including time expressed as a fractional number. A definition [way older](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#History) than any modern digital computer (*3).

Today's JDATE structure is, like all date formats defined in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Ordinal_dates) ([Full PDF](http://lists.ebxml.org/archives/ebxml-core/200104/pdf00005.pdf)) as

- 4 digit years
- optional hyphen
- 3 digit day of year

Additionally there's the truncated form ([section 5.2.2 on p.13](http://lists.ebxml.org/archives/ebxml-core/200104/pdf00005.pdf)) using two digits for year:

- 2 digit years
- optional hyphen
- 3 digit day of year

This one and without hyphen is what was the major date format within the mainframe world. Sometimes delivered by system calls as part of a combined format as mmddYYDDD, with mm and dd being month and day within a month. Within applications usually the YYDDD format was used, while user visible output was constructed from the mmddYY part, according to whatever [date format]87] the target audience preferred.

It's quite [well supported](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/24880/what-date-is-74029-on-an-ibm-mainframe/24883?noredirect=1#comment82754_24880) in modern standard libraries :))

---

*1 - Considering the noise a chain printer, even when covered, produces, some computing centers did only print at specific times - also, printers do need some handling, so personnel had to be present.

*2 - No, no mainframe programmer in his real mind would use any of the complicated formulas/algorithms [presented by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date#Calculation). They may all have their theoretical benefits, but real world programmers made simply a table of 12 integers holding the day number for the first of each month minus 1, reducing it to a simple indexing operation and addition of the day of month, corrected by +1 for leap years.

`=Y(0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334)`

*3 - Another time computer jargon picked up some well defined term and mangled it for worse, just to later state its interpretation is the only one :)) I, for example, only learned about the astronomical definition way later - in fact, for long time I took the computer version as being the same.

Comment: And what is `15/28/03`?

Comment: @dirkt Simply the time of compilation. 15 Uhr 28 und 3 Sekunden :))

Comment: Wikipedia doesn't even list a source for those algorithms (Zeller?)

Comment: @dirkt - why, the 15th day of the 28th month of 1903, of course.

Comment: @dirkt About 0.179 .